# JavaScript DOM - document instance of?

Tags: javascript, dom, instance, document

I'm new to JavaScript. I can't understand, how is it possible the document object to be an instance of window object (window.document), and also instance of HTMLDocument? Also, the HTMLDocument, is an instance of which object?

Comment: Why do you think the document object is an instance of the window object? If I have an object `foo` and it has a property `bar` which contains the string `"hello"` would you think that `foo.bar` (which remember, is a string) is an instance of `foo`?

Comment: `window.document` just means that `document` is a **property** of `window`. It's not an instance of window. `window` is the *global* object. Every global variable is a property of the global object (and vice versa).

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript's class model is not as strict as other Object Oriented languages.

You are freely allowed to add properties to class instances:

```
var now = new Date();
now.foo = "bar";
```

`document` is an instance of `HTMLDocument` and has a lot of the properties of `window` slapped onto it. `document` is not an instance of `window`. Multiple inheritance doesn't exist in JavaScript.

Comment: Even in a stricter language, the `Window` interface is specified to have a `.document` slot of type `Document` (`HTMLDocument`)